# Firebase security rules with wildcards

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I've got a data structure like this:

[image]

How can I access `/Restaurant/-KK37k6g5cYYippEHpZ3/User/-KK37k6g5cYYippEHpZ4/id`'s value within the firebase security rules? The two push keys should be wildcards. I need something like this:

```
"Restaurant": {
        "$id": {
            ".read": "auth.uid != null",
            ".write": "data.child($id).child('User').child($anotherWildcard).child('id').val() === auth.uid"  
        }
    }
```

Comment: it would be nice if you give us some background on what logic you are trying to achieve. Let me guess. Are you trying to ensure that the user will have write access to the restaurant if he has an order on this restaurant? Or do you want to give write access only to the users order?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, changed the above query. User has the same structure as Order. I want to give write access only to users which are a member of this restaurant.

Comment: srry but now i'm more confused. why would you have 2 ids inside an user? why are u doing `restaurantId/User/id/id`? what are those 2 ids?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Hey @dabo, let me know if my answer was not clear or you still have any other concern. thanks!

Comment: @adolfosrs your answer is clear and I will try it, just got some data loss here, will respond soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood what you are asking for but here goes my thoughts.

The first problem in your rule is that you are specifying `child($id)` but  you already are inside the `$id`. it is implicit in your `data` that you are referring to `$id`.

To resolve your main problem you wont need another wildcard. You can just use `hasChild` to verify if the `auth.uid` is inside `restaurant/user`.

```
"Restaurant": {
   "$id": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null && data.child('User').hasChild(auth.uid)"
   }
}
```

Comment: After refactoring my data structure the .hasChild() did it for me, thanks!

Comment: The previous problem was, that data.child('User') doesn't have the UserIDs as direct childrens, but nested with PushIDs in between. A restaurant can have multiple users.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but cannot seem to get it to work. (I can't get the wildcard `$id` to match)  Please can you have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888876/firebase-database-rules-to-match-row