# Firebase Database Rules to match row

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using a Firebase Realtime Database.  I have the following data:

[image]

I also have the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "chat": {
        "$key": {
            ".read": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid && data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid",         
            ".write": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid"          
        }
      },
```

The initial rule works perfectly:

```
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
```

**Problem**

The following 2 rules have no effect.

```
      "chat": {
        "$key": {
            ".read": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid && data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid",         
            ".write": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid"          
        }
      },
```

As you can see, in order to test these rules, in the first rule, I have made an impossible condition of `memberId1` and `memberId2` both equal to the users `uid`. As a result I would expect it to fail.

If I remove:

```
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
```

and just have:

```
      "chat": {
        "$key": {
            ".read": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid",         
            ".write": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid"          
        }
      },
```

Then access is denied. Even if I change it to:

```
 "data.child('memberId1').val() === 'h6qQg5YfQveTaCyBEXwDMSJPqwk1'
```

The following is also denied:

```
  "chat": {
    "Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7": {
        ".read": true,
```

**Question**

How should I structure the rules to allow that a user may only access a row where their `uid` matches either `memberId1` or `memberId2`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have the following code:

```
   findChats(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
            }
        }).map(items => {
            const filtered = items.filter(
                item => (item.memberId1 === this.me.uid || item.memberId2 === this.me.uid)
            );
            return filtered;
        });
    }
```

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773478/firebase-security-rules-with-wildcards). I try the following with no success:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "chat": {
        "$id": {
            ".read": true
        }
      },
```

Comment: how are you trying to read? Please add the code where you read the data.

Comment: Hi  adolfosrs, thanks for the reply. I have added an UPDATE above that shows how I query the database.  Is my problem that I don't have a full jsonpath (only `/chat/`)? Is there a way to implement this rule with this jsonpath?

Comment: hope the answer helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase rules are atomic. So if you try to read `/chat` (and thats what you are currently doing) it will only check the `/chat` branch rules. Since you dont have any rule in `/chat` it goes for the default thats is not giving access. Therefore, your rules would only be evaluated in case you were trying to read `/chat/chatId`.

One possible solution you could go for is to store a list of chats which each user is part of. So you can keep your current chat branch but store another branch in the database with the following structure:

```
user_chats: {
    uid1: {
        chatId1: true,
        chatId2: false
    }
    uid2: ...
}
```

And rules:

```
"user_chats": {
   "$uid": {
       ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
       ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
   }
}
```

Then you could keep your `chat` rules like you already have them but first get the data from `/user_chats/uid` and then for each `chatId` retrieved you you will need to read on `chat/chatId`.

Comment: Thanks adolfosrs, that makes sense to me now why it was not working. Thanks for the advise on a potential solution too.

Comment: Does this mean the answer in the following question is incorrect? (I certainly cannot get it working as they suggest) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773478/firebase-security-rules-with-wildcards

Comment: Sorry, could you be more clear on what do you think is incorrect? I think your are trying to compare different problems.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I didn't understand the question in that link correctly. It is different to my example in that they are not constrained to the a jsonpath query like mine is.

Comment: Is there a way of putting a wildcard in the query? e.g. `this.af.database.list('/chat/$key/h6qQg5YfQveTaCyBEXwDMSJPqwk1', ...`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework you are using but with the plain javascript sdk you would go with `firebase.database().ref(`chat/${chatId}`).once('value', snap => console.log(snap.val())`