# JsonPath used for Firebase Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, jsonpath

I have the following data:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
   findChats(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
            }
        }).map(items => {
            const filtered = items.filter(
                item => (item.memberId1 === this.me.uid || item.memberId2 === this.me.uid)
            );
            return filtered;
        });
    }
```

If I use the JsonPath above (`'/chat/'`) to access the database, it returns all matching rows, and then the code filters the results.

I do define the following Database Rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "chat": {
        "$key": {
            ".read": true
        }
      },
                ....
```

Which I test in the Simulator with:

```
/chat/-Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7/memberId
```

And it finds a match.

Now when I run the code with this rule, I get:

> Error: permission_denied at /chat: Client doesn't have permission to
>   access the desired data

**Question**

Is the reason I cannot get the codes JsonPath to pass the rule because it's just `/chat/`?

In order for it to match the rule, does the codes JsonPath also have to contain a `$key` and `memberId`?

e.g. `/chat/-Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7/memberId`

As you can see from my code, I am trying to get a list of filtered `chats`, and the code does not know what the `$key` values are. So is it impossible to apply a rule to the query that will only allow access to matching rows?

**UPDATE**

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773478/firebase-security-rules-with-wildcards). I try the following with no success:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "chat": {
        "$id": {
            ".read": true
        }
      },
```

**UPDATE**

I currently have the following rule, that works, but it's not adequate. It checks that the user is authenticated, but not that their `auth.id` equals either the `memberId1` or `memberId2`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chat": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "message": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting the error is that Firebase rules cascade.

Please take a look at the "Read and Write Rules Cascade" and "Rules Are Not Filters" sections of [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

Cascading essentially means the following :-

> .read and .write rules work from top-down, with shallower rules overriding deeper rules. If a rule grants read or write permissions at a particular path, then it also grants access to all child nodes under it.

Therefore, if a rule restricts access ( or if the rule is absent ) to a higher node, then you can not access that node.

So, in your case, you can test it out by accessing the `/chat/-Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7/memberId` path from your client code, and you'll see that it works.

The following example from the Firebase doc is a replica of your situation :-

> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every affected child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail completely. Consider this structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "records": {
      "rec1": {
        ".read": true
      },
      "rec2": {
        ".read": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Without understanding that rules are evaluated atomically, it might
>   seem like fetching the /records/ path would return rec1 but not rec2.
>   The actual result, however, is an error:

Comment: Hi Rohan, thank you for the great explanation. Then because rules are atomic, it means with my current AngularFire2 implementation with the jsonpath `return this.af.database.list('/chat/',`, it is not possible for me to add the rule that you may only access chats with a matching `memberId1`.

Comment: My problem is that when I run the query, I don't know what the `$key` (`-Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7`) is. e.g. `/chat/-Ko7w9XTtuRVN4p6CMp7/memberId`

Comment: Hey Richard! Glad I could help.

Comment: Do you know if there's any other way to enforce the security rule? i.e. Only allow access to rows that match `uid == memberId`?

Comment: To answer your question - you'll definitely have to put a Firebase Rule above the `/chat` node.

Comment: Yes, there's a way. I'll make an edit to my answer. But before that, tell me this - is the `memberId` the auth id of the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes, the `memberId` is the `auth.id` of the logged in user. As you can see in the database, a message has a `memberId1` and `memberId2`. The rule is that either one of the two must match the `auth.id` (just like the filter applied in the AngulatFire2 query).  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Does that mean that you want to retrieve all chats that have the the `auth.uid` as either `memberId1` or `memberId2`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry then, because of cascading, this isn't possible. You see, if you don't have a `.read` rule on `/chats`, then you can't access the child chats. And, if you have a `.read` on `/chats`, then you'd automatically be able to read the entire child data. So, as a rule of thumb. Filtering can't be achieved using rules. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's a shame, I will need to look at an alternative plan. Thank you for your help, it's been very informative.

Comment: However, you can tweak your database to achieve what you're trying to achieve. For example, whenever a user starts to participate in a new chat, add the chat's key to a different node that could be something like this - `/UsersChats/userId/chatId`

Comment: Now, if you want to get all chats of a particular user, just access the `/UserChats/userId` path, and get all the keys. Then retrieve the chat details from the path given in the question.

Comment: p.s. I don't think this is possible, but will I be able to change the AngularFire2 query to contain a wildcard (`$key`) to access the `chat`? e.g. `this.af.database.list('/chat/$key/memberId'`

Comment: Using this, you can have stringent database rules that only allow a given user to access his `/UsersChats/userId` node and other advantages.

Comment: Let me ask you, why are you using database rules in the first place? Is it to filter data or for privacy? Because the condition you defined is a very standard query!

Comment: That doesn't fit my business model unfortunately. Because I need two users to be able to access the same chat. Hence `memberId1` and `memberId2`. Unless I combine the two to make the `userId`.

Comment: So you can save the chat key under both the users' personal list because that is how denormalising of data works. I hope you do find the solution that suits you the most. All the best!

Comment: To answer, the AngularFire2 query is applying the filter, so the functionality is working fine as is. The reason I am adding the Firebase database Rule, is for security. What happens if a hacker wants to access someone else's messages.

Comment: To answer, the AngularFire2 query is applying the filter, so the functionality is working fine as is. The reason I am adding the Firebase database Rule, is for security. What happens if a hacker wants to access someone else's messages.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.